# Using Retrofit with Asycntask is necessary?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am new to Android development and it's my first time on API. I am getting a message log that **application main thread may working too much** . I am using Retrofit with **enqueue** callback, a java class Model.
I just want to take advice from you guys that should I use **AsyncTask** to make application working smooth? or Retrofit is already doing the work like that of **AsyncTask**? or is there a need or not of **AsyncTask** in my application?.

I have been searching this for few days but I am confused

**Note**

1. I am using the Picasso library for downloading the image and an
   image would be 100 kb in size.
2. Also as the application is still in its build there is no too much data on the server.

**Purpose**
I just want the application to work smooth and good on all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTask is deprecated
[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Retrofit has its own async calls mechanism which is far more appropriate
[Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests).

Also, you can use rxJava with retrofit which will help you even more in creating async calls.

Comment: so i should use retrofit with rxJava to make performance good? Or retrofit already doing it?

Comment: The performance overhead of using rxjava won't be large.
So, using them both would be fine.